# How to make IOS ask to grant permissions to access user accounts

Tags: objective-c

```
[self.ACAstore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    self.bPermissionToAccessStoreGranted=granted;
    [self vContinue];
    // Handle any error state here as you wish
}];
```

The result of granted is simply false. I want users to get get asked first.

The possible cause is that the iPhone has no twitter accounts. In which case I want to display a twitter login page so user can sign up.

Comment: Do you want to ask the user if he wants to allow this before performing the above code? Like with some popup (Alert)?

Comment: I think so but I think it's something iOS would do.

Comment: Ok, I mean it's not hard to create that Alert to ask the user, but it seems like there's some other problem if `granted` is always returning false. I haven't tried any authentications using twitter so I can't help you with that. I can only help you with setting up the Alert.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.ACAstore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
if(granted)
{
    [self vContinue];
}
else {
    // Handle any error state here as you wish
}
}];
```

Do you want this?

Comment: I did that. Instead, iOS simply deny the request silently.

Comment: are there simply no accounts that conform to twitterType?